# Using CSV.Reader in 2 functions, only one function will read the csv file while the other will act as if the file is not being read

Tags: python, csv

I do not understand why it is that my program will run the first function getcars() just fine and return all the cars but then when I want to run get_cars_older_than_x_years() it will skip the for loop in the function and not execute the code in the function.

I only get this occurring when I try to call both functions. When I only call one of the functions i.e. I call get_cars_older_than_x_years() it will execute the code as it should.

```
import csv, datetime


def get_cars():
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line[0])


def get_cars_older_than_x_years(x):
    print("Following cars are older than", x, "years old.")
    for line in csv_reader:
        age = datetime.date.today().year - int(line[1])
        if age > x:
            print(line)


with open('cars.csv', 'r') as csv_file:  # read file cars.csv
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)  # will read the file

    get_cars()
    get_cars_older_than_x_years(10)
```

Comment: once you've read the lines in a file you need to either close/open the file again or `seek(0)`. Once you've read the csv in `get_cars`, game over.

Comment: In other words, if you want to read the file twice, you will need to `open()` it twice.

Comment: However you do it, saving and then reusing the results from reading it the first time would probably be a good idea (as long as the data isn't _too_ large).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)  # will read the file
```

doesn't actually read the file. The first thing that enumerates `csv_reader` will read the file. But any future enumerations come back empty because you have reached the end. You can do the read once when the file is first opened and then use that table in your other calls. An easy way to that is with `list()`.

```
import csv, datetime

def get_cars():
    for line in car_table:
        print(line[0])

def get_cars_older_than_x_years(x):
    print("Following cars are older than", x, "years old.")
    for line in car_table:
        age = datetime.date.today().year - int(line[1])
        if age > x:
            print(line)

with open('cars.csv', 'r') as csv_file:  # read file cars.csv
    car_table = list(csv.reader(csv_file))  # will read the file
# exit 'with' so that file closes
get_cars()
get_cars_older_than_x_years(10)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I did not realise that you could use 'for line' in a list.

Comment: @RenwarKarim - yes, you can use `for` with anything that is iterable. Lists, dicts, sets, strings, etc... iterable containers are all over the place in python.